# OSError: `LIBFM_PATH` is not set

Tags: python-2.7

I recently installed libFM and using pywFM

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pywFM

I followed the instructions, and set LIBFM_PATH as

```
export LIBFM_PATH=/Users/raon/Dropbox/Python/libfm/libfm/bin/
```

which is the location of the /bin/ folder

when I try to run the example provided in the link above, I get the following error:

```
fm = pywFM.FM(task='regression', num_iter=5)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-14-d2c7380843b8>", line 1, in <module>
    fm = pywFM.FM(task='regression', num_iter=5)

  File "/Users/raon/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pywFM/__init__.py",     line 105, in __init__
raise OSError("`LIBFM_PATH` is not set. Please install libFM and set the path variable (https://github.com/jfloff/pywFM#installing).")

OSError: `LIBFM_PATH` is not set. Please install libFM and set the path variable (https://github.com/jfloff/pywFM#installing).
```

Any idea how to rectify the (presumably incorrect) setting of LIBFM_PATH here?